# importrange using conditions, NO_COLUMN error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has information about students on it that I want to share to another sheet based on a date.  Basically what I have is a discipline referral system to track information for myself, but when I indicate that a student is to serve a detention I have to manually add that to another sheet that is then tracked by the teacher that monitors those detentions.  What I would like is for when I indicate a detention on my sheet that it automatically populates to the other teacher's sheet based on a date.

Referral sheet information:  Column E has student names, Column U has date of detention

Teacher's monitor sheet:  the date for each detention is listed in AG1 for example.

I want the query to find all the dates in Column U of my sheet, that match the date in AG1 of the teachers, and place the student names in the column under the date in AG1.

This is what I have created so far but keep getting an "unable to parse query string for function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN:Col21" error.

=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KS0FRuHnFdg4oHd31RfAaEoCwjHvhWwHAgCBA42Sajs/edit?resourcekey#gid=462178060","Form Responses 1!E2:E"),"where Col21='AG1'")

Comment: I have addressed the issue and created a work around, the problem was that there were missing (blank) cells in Col21.  Is there a fix to this?  I rewrote column 21 as =if(isblank(v2)"NO CONSEQUENCE","V2") and then filled this all the way down my sheet, that then accomplished my goal.  Is there a cleaner way so I don't have to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the whole range in which you need to apply the conditions in the query inside the IMPORTRANGE. For example:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KS0FRuHnFdg4oHd31RfAaEoCwjHvhWwHAgCBA42Sajs/edit?resourcekey#gid=462178060","Form Responses 1!A2:U"),"Select Col5 where Col21='"&AG1&"'")
```

Or:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KS0FRuHnFdg4oHd31RfAaEoCwjHvhWwHAgCBA42Sajs/edit?resourcekey#gid=462178060","Form Responses 1!E2:U"),"Select Col1 where Col17='"&AG1&"'")
```

And if you need to compare it to a cell you should close quotes and add the value of the cell `'"&AG1&"'"`

Answer (score 0):

use this first to allow access:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1KS0FRuHnFdg4oHd31RfAaEoCwjHvhWwHAgCBA42Sajs", "Form Responses 1!E2")
```

then use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1KS0FRuHnFdg4oHd31RfAaEoCwjHvhWwHAgCBA42Sajs", "Form Responses 1!E2:E"), 
 "where Col1='AG1'", )
```